# How can I specify that curl (via command line) overwrites a file if it already exists?

Tags: filenames, io, curl

I'm using curl in this syntax:

`curl -o myfile.jpg http://example.com/myfile.jpg`

If I run this command twice, I get two files:

```
myfile.jpg
myfile-1.jpg
```

How can I tell Curl that I want it to overwrite the file if it exists?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: what `curl` version on which system?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of using `-o` option to write to a file, use your shell to direct the output to the file:

```
curl http://example.com/myfile.jpg > myfile.jpg
```

Comment: And beforehand, make sure you do not have the `noclobber` option enabled (`set +o noclobber`).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. That does not make curl overwrite the existing file, that makes the shell overwrite the (potentially) existing file with what curl sent to stdout. So it's incompatible with `-JO`.

Answer (score 5):

Pass `--clobber`. This also covers server-provided filename when using `-J`.

Comment: ... since 2022 -- long after the previous answers were written.

Comment: It's still useful to mention it for anyone reaching here from Google (like myself).

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem, and I wanted to reuse the same filename regardless of what the server-side returns.  In your case, you can get the filename with `basename`:

```
➸ basename 'http://example.com/myfile.jpg'
myfile.jpg
```

Then you can write a helper Bash function like:

```
➸ function download { name="$(basename $1)"; curl "$1" > "$name"; }
➸ download 'http://example.com/myfile.jpg'
```

In my case, however, the filename is not even part of the URL; it comes with the `Content-Disposition` header.  With Curl the command line is:

```
➸ curl -fSL -R -J -O 'http://example.com/getData.php?arg=1&arg2=...'
```

You may ignore the `-fSL` if you want -- It handles if the server-side returns `302 Redirection`.  The relevant flags here are:

- `-R` for server-side timestamp
- `-J` to consider server-side `Content-Disposition`
- `-O` to switch to download behavior instead of dumping on terminal

However, it still suffers from refusing to overwrite if file name exists.  I want it to overwrite if server side `Last-Modified` timestamp is newer.

So I end up with a wget solution that's able to do so:

```
➸ wget -NS --content-disposition 'http://example.com/getData.php?arg=1&arg2=...'
```

- `-N` is to check server side timestamp and overwrite only when server side has new version
- `--content-disposition` is to consider the `Content-Disposition` header
- wget's default behavior is to download, to the filename given from server side.

In your case, if you don't care about the timestamp, it's just:

```
➸ wget -O myfile.jpg http://example.com/myfile.jpg
```